# IPhone - Sample for developing Video Chat app using IOS SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, video-streaming, videochat

I am looking for a sample helloworld app (or a tutorial) to develop a video chat using IOS SDK.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.iphonegamezone.net/ios-tutorial-create-iphone-video-chat-app-using-parse-and-opentok-tokbox/) written by myself that uses tokbox api for streaming and Parse.com for user management backend:

Opentok charges you based on api requests and all 3rd party providers will follow that model. The benefit to you would be you can scale based on demand, with some volume obtained for free. You may have your own judgement though. I do not work for, neither vouch for tokbox or parse, the link is just a guideline.

Comment: That's an amazing tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [OpenTok API](http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api). That will make things much faster. Creating a video chat app from ground up will take some time and considerable amount of expertise.

Comment: But it seems not free .. http://www.tokbox.com/opentok/api/pricing

Comment: Group chats - yes its not free. For 1-1 calls, no recording (the very basic needs), it is free

Comment: @lostInTransit, Thanks for the recommendation, would you still recommend OpenTok in 2017 or do you have any other recommendations ?

Comment: Definitely not! Now theres quickblox, Twilio and even AppRTC